# My C drive is full, but on the same hard disk I have 2 other partitions with gigs of space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

My hard drive used to have 2 gigs of free space (C drive), and no idea why but it is now full.  I have tried clean disk, removing things using jgoodies disk report etc. but have no idea where that space went, it could have been system updates?

Anyhow, on the same drive, but different partition I have gigs of space (drives D and E).

Is there a free utility to reblance the free space over to the C drive?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Easeus Partition Manager. Get the free version:

http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm

Comment: Can I free up space from the other partitions without deleting them?

Comment: @user27449 Yes, that is the point of that software: You can resize your partitions; take space away from one, and give it to the other without losing data. That said, although I have never had this type of software fail in 17 years, you should make sure that any important files are backed up. The risk is very minimal, but does technically exist.

Comment: so I resized drive D by removing about 7 GIGS, and now it shows up as unallocated space.  How do I move that to drive C?

Comment: Resize C into that unallocated space.

Comment: so I select the C drive, click on resize/move, then what?

Comment: Pull the little dot on the right hand side of the slider all the way over into that unallocated space. Then you can Apply the changes. The other thing you can do is simply type in the partition size in the middle block until it has filled the empty space.

Comment: The problem is that it is already maxed out, I guess the move operation didn't work (i.e. moving the newly allocated space to the C drive).  Maybe I don't understand, I want to move the new allocated space (I made it a partition with drive letter S) to the C parition.

Comment: ok figured it out, I had to slide the space from drive D to make space for C i.e. the space has to be next to the drive I want to expand which is wierd, anyhow, thanks man! thanks for the offer to help over the phone also!

Comment: Oh, glad you got it. Now that you see how it works, and they almost all work the same, see how easy it really was? Very cool you got it. :)

Comment: P.S. I am also glad you got it because I want to go to bed, but I wanted to finish helping you.

Comment: Care to explain (in your answer) what he's supposed to do with it?

Answer (score 4):

[My answer](https://superuser.com/questions/307869/my-windows-directory-is-huge/307924#307924) on the question [My windows directory is huge](https://superuser.com/q/307869/82434) would also help you with your question.

> Run [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) and see if you can find any unusually large files. The program displays all of your files graphically:
>
> [image: WinDirStat]
>
> Sometimes you can find a large corrupted file that is entirely useless.

Comment: this image is just so cool :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Windows 7 Disk Management.  Look at the example picture (Disk 0) on [this web site](http://www.theeldergeek.com/disk_management.htm)

1. Assuming you have 3 partitions, C, D, E, move everything off of D and onto E.
2. Delete the D partition (which will destroy all data on it
3. Right click on the C: drive and choose Extend.  You may be asked if it is OK to change
   the drive type to Dynamic -- this will be OK.
4. Your C: drive will now be the size of the original C: plus the size of the former D:    drive.

See also: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/

Comment: Nothing personal, but that is like doing surgery to pop a zit. That is 100X harder than using true partioning software.

Comment: My D drive has programs installed, I can't just move it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can backup the contents of the D drive or are prepared for the contents to be deleted you can use the **built-in Windows 7 Disk Management tool.**

How to resize C drive using Disk Management:

1. Open the Windows Start Menu and right-click on ‘Computer’
2. Select ‘Manage’
3. From the left hand menu, select ‘Disk Management’
4. Right-click on the ‘D’ partition and select ‘Delete volume’
5. Select ‘Yes’
6. Right-click on the ‘C’ partition and select ‘Extend Volume’
7. Select ‘Next’ ‘Next’ then ‘Finished’
8. The C drive is now extended to use the space the D drive did use.

**Source:** [Windows 7 - How to resize Hard Drive Partitions](http://mockbox.net/windows-7/332-windows-7-how-to-resize-hard-drive-partitions.html)

*Source is a personal blog I run.*