# Why does my Windows 7 64-bit installation take up 151GB of hard drive space?

Tags: windows-7

I have a 222GB hard drive. After installing Windows 7 64-bit and Microsoft Office 2010, it shows:

- **Used space**: 151 GB
- **Free space**: 70 GB

Is it normal for the OS to be taking up 151 GB of hard drive space?

Comment: Was is a fresh install or did you update from a previous OS?

Comment: No this is not normal. I second @Windos's question... If it was an update, it might have kept some data from the previous OS, or it could also be a HD formatting error

Comment: It was fresh install. Previous system was Vista 32 bit and this is Windows7. Is there any way to free up space.

Comment: Can you tell us the individual sizes of your `C:\Windows` and `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office` folders?

Comment: I suppose it was a HD error. Try reformatting it using another tools first, say a Linux live CD, or by the Windows 7 Recovery Console

Comment: When you say "fresh install," does that mean you completely wiped the drive? What I'm asking is did you delete the system partition and then re-create it? If all you did was a "new installation" into the existing Vista partition, much would be left behind from the Vista install.

Comment: Maybe this: http://superuser.com/questions/307869/my-windows-directory-is-huge/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting that the drive was not formatted. Since you went form x86 to x64, you'd have to make a custom install.  Look to see if there is a Windows.old Folder.  That has all your old Vista files.

If you don't need any of your old files, it is safe to delete the folder.

Comment: Windows.old Folder was culprit.

Comment: @Tom: Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not at all normal.

First, I recommend running chkdisk to find out if something is wrong with the file system. Right-click on your hard drive, choose Properties, then on the Tools page choose "Check Now".

If there really is 151 GB of used space, then you can use [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to discover which folders are taking up all the space. Run the utility and it will uncover where all the space has gone.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to check if System Protection is using up a lot of space. Go to `Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> System Protection` and check how much disk space is reserved for the drive.  Use the configure button to reduce the amount to 5-10% or whatever is a desirable amount.

Comment: +1.  Mine was set at 50% and I've been crawling along low on space.

Answer (score 1):

On this drive, enable View Hidden Files and see if there are any Temporary files being created.  Look for the size of **pagefile.sys** and **hiberfil.sys** on your root directory.

Also, Office 2010 preserves its Setup file on your computer, look for the size of **\MSOCache** folder.

If time permits, I would right click on each folder on this drive and note the size.  This will help me to locate the folders which are taking up most of the Hard Disk space.

Comment: And of course for the folder \SystemVolumeInformation