# Windows 7 volume missing

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

after cleaning `C:\Windows` directory from `$path\SoftwareDistribution` I won 2GB.

It's okay, and I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2010. Everything went ok and     `C:\Windows` size increased to 17GB. But after a several hours, it's become over 22GB!

I can't understand that and trying to free some space. `$path\SoftwareDistribution` is less than 0.5 GB.

So, all hidden directories are shown, but in `C:\Windows` hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> the size is shown as 16GB but the properties for `C:\Windows` show that it's 22GB.

Why is this difference there? What can I do to get the space back?

Comment: Sounds like the same question I answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/307869/my-windows-directory-is-huge/307894#307894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is not recommended to delete any files from within the C:\Windows folder, except service pack and patch backups.

I recommend that you use [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) to accurately calculate the amount of space being used on your computer, including in the Windows folder. I believe it accurately doesn't double-count hard links which are common in the WinSxS folder.

Comment: People need to stop confusing themselves.  They are trying to untangle something that was created by thousands of software engineers with more degrees than you can shake a stick at.  It's like trying to take apart an engine with zero auto experience.

Comment: okay, but how count of files and their size can help me free C:\Windows folder?

Comment: i have found that winsxs contains many directories like x86_microsoft-windows-(naturallanguage|s..chrecognizerenu.ale)_31bf3856as364e35)6.1.7600 ... and so on. can i delete them?

Comment: Do NOT touch the winsxs folder, ever. It contains copies of various versions of DLLs that different programs need to use. It may look like it's using a lot of space, but a lot of it is hardlinks (duplicate file system entries pointing to the same physical file). Deleting anything in that folder can cause programs or parts of Windows to stop functioning.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSXS