# preventing Windows from filling up system disk

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My windows directory is huge](https://superuser.com/questions/307869/my-windows-directory-is-huge)

I spare 30G for C:\ for Windows 7. As time goes by Windows fill it up.

I do not know what can be removed. How can this be solved?

Comment: are you trying to say that you used to have 30GB of free space which filled up on its own?

Comment: @chmod No. My c:\ is 30GB and Windows consumes more and more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The c:\windows folder will grow, however you may want to check `c:\users` which is where your users profiles are kept.  This includes documents, photos, application settings, temporary file etc.

This folder can grow at a faster rate than the windows folders, and it is usually easier to target what is consuming space.  For example, if you have lots of music or images you can move them to a different drive.

I find [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) is a good tool for identifying where space is taken up, and can quickly show large files at a glance.

Don't delete anything unless you are sure it is not critical.

Comment: How can I move application settings and temporary files to other disk?

Comment: @onemach http://superuser.com/questions/6391/moving-users-folder-on-windows-vista-seven-to-another-partition